# Issue with jQuery 'combo button' click handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I'm looking for some help with a button interaction I'm putting together.

The idea is that the user will click the "RESET" button, and then have to cancel or confirm in order to reset a form.

The .replace() methods are working as expected, and my "RESET" button becomes a "CANCEL" / "CLEAR" combo button like I want./

The problem is that when I click "CANCEL" (or the "CLEAR" button, for now...) and it goes back to the normal "RESET" button, I can no longer click on the "RESET" button to repeat the process.

At a guess, my issue lies in either:

- handling the .click() event(s), but I can't figure it out. Various combinations of 'return false' and .unbind("click") haven't helped.
- the .replace() method is screwing up my event bindings maybe?

Any guidance is, of course, greatly appreciated! A Codepen demo link is at the bottom.

Thanks - JR (p.s.: please forgive my probably clunky jQuery - still new here)

```
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $(this)
          .replaceWith(
            '<div id="resetGroup" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">' +
            '<div class="btn-group" role="group">' +
            '<input id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="CANCEL" />' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="btn-group" role="group">' +
            '<input id="clear" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="CLEAR" />' +
            '</div></div>'
          )
          .unbind("click");

      $("#cancel").click(function() {
          // GO BACK TO THE REGULAR "RESET" BUTTON //
          $("#resetGroup").replaceWith(
            '<input class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="reset" type="button" value="RESET" />'
          );
      });

      $("#clear").click(function() {
          // DO RESET STUFF HERE BEFORE GOING BACK TO THE REGULAR "RESET" BUTTON //
          $("#resetGroup").replaceWith(
            '<input class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="reset" type="button" value="RESET" />'
          );
      });
    });
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/jriggles/pen/rpwZQo?editors=0011)

Comment: FWIW: when using the "accepted answer" from below, it makes no difference whether or not I use `.unbind("click")` in the main function. _YMMV_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are "replaced"... Consider them dynamically generated.

You'll have to define your handlers differently, by using "delegation".

Example:

```
$(document).on("click","#reset",function(){
  // The rest is the same
});
```

Do it for all element that gets replaced.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have taken care of it perfectly!